# What are Sabotage points?

Tags: optional-rules, bubblegumshoe

The optional rules for Sabotage points (BGS 66) look pretty great, except... I'm unclear what they *are.* I get what Sabotage points do, and I like it. But are Sabotage points some additional resource (if so, how many does a Sleuth get? what build points are spent on them, or are they awarded ad-hoc by the GM?), or is it a fancy way of re-naming existing ability points when they're being spent for the purpose of Sabotage?

Answer (score 3):

From BGS p.66:

> the Sleuths may do something that promises to embarrass or irritate or otherwise damage the Cool of an NPC: post their love email to Instagram, or date their sister, or plant weed in their locker. If the player wishes, she can set the trigger for Cool damage by spending **points from another ability, or SABOTAGE POINTS.** In the examples above, she might spend from Computers or Gossip (to hack the email or get it on the down low), from Flirting (to attract the sister), or from Filch or Repair (to plant the weed or open the locker undetected).

My reading is that "or SABOTAGE POINTS" is an appositive phrase, renaming "points from another ability" for the purposes of this rule.

Pool points spent to do this time-delayed cool damage **become** sabotage points, they are not purchased separately with build points or in any other way.

The requirement seems to be that if the sabotage action would have required a successful roll, that roll must be made and succeed before sabotage points may be spent from the concordant ability.